# Django ORM getting cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I've got class in models:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    region_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column="region_id")
    region_name=models.CharField(max_length=4000,blank=True,db_column="region_name")
    def __str__(self):
        return f"region_id={self.region_id}, region_name={self.region_name}"
    class Meta:
        db_table = "regions"
```

Now I'm trying to query database from shell:

```
python manage.py shell
>>>s=Region.objects.all()
>>>s
```

When I'm connected to PostgreSQL everything is fine, but when I connect to Oracle (has same table) I'm getting "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" doing the same as with PostgreSQL. Is there some bug in cx_Oracle or what?

Please help, I spent few hours on that issue.

Comment: Can you share your `DATABASES` setting and the version of Django, Oracle and Python you are using

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'XE',
        'USER': 'hr',
        'PASSWORD': 'hr',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '1521'
    }
}

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?  You can write an answer to your own question.  That will definitely help others.